# How to simulate magnetic field of a toroidal solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, simulations, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I am trying to simulate the magnetic flux inside and outside of a classic toroidal solenoid. The simulation must be able to simulate a toroidal solenoid with several densely wound layers of copper wire.

The issue is that I can create a toroidal coil from a parametric curve, but am limited to one layer of windings and am computationally limited in my number of turns (meshing alone takes hours). COMSOL allows you to create coils by defining a direction of current flow and specifying a number of turns. This would solve the meshing problem, but I have not been able to implement this for a toroidal coil. I am unsure of how to proceed.

Which simulation tool should I investigate for this task? **In short, I have looked into ANSYS and COMSOL, but have trouble creating a simulation of the magnetic field through a toroidal solenoid with multiple layers of windings.**

I would be extremely grateful for any pointers, as I have been puzzling over this for two weeks.

Comment: This is not a physics question but an Electrical Engineering question.

Comment: Do you have a specific surface you want to find the flux through?

Comment: @RickyTensor I want to find the flux through the air surrounding the solenoid, both in the air core and the exterior/surroundings.

Comment: Okay, I'll interpret that as a half plane extending out from the axis of the torus. You should be able to compute the flux through that half plane from a small segment of current using the Biot-Savart law. (For something as simple as a half plane, there's probably an analytical formula.) Then just integrate over all the segments in your wire. Sanity check using this page: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/toroid.html